# Generation of 11 bit random number

Tags: cryptography, randomness, pseudo-random-generators

I need camera to sign one random line(there are something like 2000 lines) from the frame each second. 
At the beginning I have some 64 bits seed with high entropy from physical RNG and a secure channel with camera. How should I generate the needed number?

Comment: What do you mean by "sign"?  When you say "the needed number", what number are you referring to?  When you talk about a "secure channel with camera", what is on the other end of that channel?  What are you trying to achieve?  What threats are you trying to protect against?  What approaches have you already considered, and why have you rejected them?